# JavaWS behaviour while running JNLP in debug mode

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm trying to debug an applet running with JNLP. I've prepared a script for that:

`#!/bin/sh
export JAVAWS_TRACE_NATIVE=1
export JAVAWS_VM_ARGS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8989,server=y,suspend=y"
javaws "$@"`

it works, at least it runs my jnlp and opens listening port. At the beginning it waits for the debugger to attach - which is OK. However, it drops the connection when attached to it and runs the same jnlp again without any listening port set. Which means I can't attach to that process anymore. 
I've enabled java console to see more and... even running javaws jnlpfile.jnlp it opens the applet (with java console) then closes it (java console is closed as well) and opens that again.

I'm on Linux Mint 18.3.

Java: 1.8.0_161